# The image path is weird and I cannot see any image after deploying my Next.js application

Tags: reactjs, next.js, cloudflare

I'm new to web development. This might be a stupid question, but I can't figure it out after consulting countless pages, so I'm plucking up the courage to ask.

I've built the source code with Next.js `v13.3`, but the image paths are getting weird. In dev mode, the image is clearly showing up fine, but it's not working in production.

Here is my `next.config.js` file:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  distDir: "out",
  output: "export",
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

And I also tried this.

```
  images: {
    loader: "imgix",
    path: "",
  },
```

My images are all inside the public folder, and routing works fine. After building, the image partial source looks like this:

[image]

If you run npm run start with output: "export" removed, it should work fine. However, I need to deploy it to Cloudflare pages, so I need to make it a static HTML file. Is there anything else I can try here?

Please help me to solve this problem. Thank you for reading!

I've tried changing the baseurl and output variables in the `next.config.js` file, and I've searched everywhere else, but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self Answer

The best way for me was to use an image loader, and write a function that references that path and returns it.

The reason I used an image loader instead of using the img tag is that I can just remove that function later when I need to optimise the image.

However, your answer is also very helpful, as I didn't even know there was such a thing as image optimisation.

Thank you so much, and thank you for welcoming me to the community.

**ImageLoader.js in root directory**

```
export default function ImageLoader({ src }) {
  return `https://example.com/${src}`;
}
```

**next.config.js file**

```
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  distDir: "out",
  output: "export",
  images: {
    loader: "custom",
    loaderFile: './ImageLoader.js'
  },
};
```

Answer (score 4):

As you can read on the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export#unsupported-features), if you use Next.js to generate a static app with `export`, features that require serverside logic won't work, like [`Image Optimization`](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/image-optimization) with `next/image` component, which you seem to have used. In this case, you need to use the native `img` tag:

```html
<img src ="/image.png"/ alt = "" />
```

The `/` means you are in the `public` folder; if your images are in some folder inside `public`, it should be:

```html
<img src ="/folder/image.png"/ alt = "" />
```

You can also import your images with their relative path to the current file. For example:

```js
import image from "../assets/image.png"/;
```

```js
<img src ={image} alt = "" />
```