# Nextjs 14 Images are not displayed in production server?

Tags: next.js, deployment, cpanel, next-images, next.js14

After I yarn run build and upload all files in the cpanel hosting my images looks like broken.
I added my server address in the package.json
Here is my next.config.js file

```
const nextConfig = {
  output: 'export', //for deployment
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

[Here is inspect img ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3mB2.png)
All images in the public folder
This is my image component

```
"use client";
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

interface ImageItemProps {
  src: string;
  alt: string;
  onClick: () => void;
}

const ImageItem: React.FC<ImageItemProps> = ({ src, alt, onClick }) => {
  return (
    <div className="relative cursor-pointer h-60" onClick={onClick}>
      <Image src={src} alt={alt} fill style={{ objectFit: "cover" }} />
      {/* Adjust width and height accordingly */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageItem;
```

This is my image json

```
[
  { "src": "/imageList1.jpg", "alt": "Image 1" },
  { "src": "/imageList2.jpg", "alt": "Image 2" },
  { "src": "/imageList3.jpg", "alt": "Image 3" },
  { "src": "/imageList4.jpg", "alt": "Image 4" },
  { "src": "/imageList5.jpg", "alt": "Image 5" },
  { "src": "/imageList6.jpg", "alt": "Image 6" }
]
```

Could you please help me to figure out Image problem.

Comment: Did you copy the public and static folders into your export folder after building? It won't do this automatically as the [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/output#automatically-copying-traced-files) explain.

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76122243/the-image-path-is-weird-and-i-cannot-see-any-image-after-deploying-my-next-js-ap

Comment: Have you got any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to change the way you are referencing the images, since they are apparently trying to search in a path where they are not, try this in your image json:

```
[
  { "src": "./imageList1.jpg", "alt": "Image 1" },
  { "src": "./imageList2.jpg", "alt": "Image 2" },
  { "src": "./imageList3.jpg", "alt": "Image 3" },
  { "src": "./imageList4.jpg", "alt": "Image 4" },
  { "src": "./imageList5.jpg", "alt": "Image 5" },
  { "src": "./imageList6.jpg", "alt": "Image 6" }
]
```

or

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";

interface ImageItemProps {
  src: string;
  alt: string;
  onClick: () => void;
}

const ImageItem: React.FC<ImageItemProps> = ({ src, alt, onClick }) => {
  const imageUrl = process.env.DOMAIN + src;

  return (
    <div className="relative cursor-pointer h-60" onClick={onClick}>
      <Image src={imageUrl} alt={alt} fill style={{ objectFit: "cover" }} />
      {/* Adjust width and height accordingly */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ImageItem;
```

process.env.DOMAIN is your domain name (example.com), this way your app can have the images referenced correctly.

Your domain environment variable can be added to the option called "Setup Node.js App" in your cPanel Dashboard.